# "qemu+ssh..." only works with PasswordAuthentication yes in sshd_config

Tags: ssh, qemu, libvirt, virsh

I can SSH from laptop to server with private/public key like this:

```
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/ed25519 chris@192.168.1.10 -p 22XX
```

My public key is on the SERVER in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

When I try `virsh` I cannot connect:

```
$ virsh -c qemu+ssh://chris@192.168.1.10:22XX/system

error: failed to connect to the hypervisor
error: Cannot recv data: chris@192.168.1.10: Permission denied (publickey).: Connection reset by peer
```

I changed `PasswordAuthentication yes` in `sshd_config` and am able to connect to SERVER with the above command.

But the problem is now I have SSH password authentication on my server that I don't want.

Here is the `journalctl` from LAPTOP attempting to connect **without** password:

```
$ journalctl --lines=100

Jan 25 18:06:05 arch polkitd[462]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:1237:24897 (system bus name :1.52 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --process 1237 --notify-fd 4 --fallback], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Jan 25 18:06:05 arch polkitd[462]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:1237:24897 (system bus name :1.52, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
```

I don't have `polkit.service` running on either LAPTOP or SERVER. And I changed `libvirtd_config` to have `auth_rw="none"` and `auth_ro="none"` and I have `qemu-ssh-block-agent` package installed.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a suggestion to use `ssh-agent` which I had tried yesterday but wasn't successful. I rebooted the server and laptop retried `ssh-agent` and it was able to connect last night.

For others: I ran it through my LAPTOP:

```sh
[chris@arch.laptop][~]
$  ssh-agent
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-XXXXXXN8xmnw/agent.1538; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=1539; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 1539;

[chris@arch.laptop][~]
$  eval $(ssh-agent -c)      //fish needs -c
Agent pid 1569

[chris@arch.laptop][~]
$  ssh-add ~/.ssh/ed25519
Identity added: /home/chris/.ssh/ed25519 (chris@arch)

[chris@arch.laptop][~]
$  virsh -c qemu+ssh://chris@192.168.1.10:220/system
Welcome to virsh, the virtualization interactive terminal.

Type:  'help' for help with commands
       'quit' to quit

virsh #
```

The only issue that remains is that from virt-manager GUI I still receive the same connection issue. So I have to start that with:

```
virt-manager -c qemu+ssh://chris@192.168.1.10:220/system
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).